# Linux Web Server Configuration

Tags: mysql, php, web-server

I am in a need to have my own web server as I use to have few websites to be tested on monthly basis.

I plan to get some cheap P4 laptop which will do that task and am planning to install Ubuntu on it for PHP, MySQL.

Can you suggest some configurations I must have including Processor, RAM, Hard Drive and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu provide lists of [certified hardware](http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/search/?search=laptop) and [minimum requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Although you want a server, your hardware is not server class, so I'd install a minimal desktop version and then install the Apache packages, this process is mentioned at the [Ubuntu website](http://bit.ly/g56vYC)

It's worth noting that Apache PHP and MySQL can be [installed on Windows](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) too.

Comment: yes I currently have on windows but Ubuntu is good for commercial use

Comment: today I came back to this post and giggled to how naive I used to be :)

Answer (score 1):

More RAM is always good, however, since you don't plan on actually hosting the sites from the laptop, anything should work.